# Physics related Podcasts

Tags: soft-question, specific-reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any good audio recordings of educational physics material?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/16626/are-there-any-good-audio-recordings-of-educational-physics-material)

In the same way that was already asked about [good books](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/884/books-that-every-physicist-should-read) of Physics in this StackExchange, I would like to know good physics podcasts! What are the most informative and enjoyable to hear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could collect the sources from various websites and place it here, browse through their content to get what you want

[Are there any good physics podcasts?](http://www.reddit.com/r/Physics/comments/ff83y/are_there_any_good_physics_podcasts/)

[Physics General Interest Seminar Podcasts](http://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/podcasts/Physics/PhysicsGenInt/podcasts.html)

[Physics Podcasts
Podcasting the mysteries of the universe](http://physics.about.com/od/classroomphysics/tp/PhysicsPodcasts.01.htm)

The first link has some good collection . Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any regular podcasts, but there are lots of Physics lectures on Youtube. Just search for something obvious like "physics".

If you follow any of the Physics blogs you'll often see links to Youtube videos posted.

JR

Comment: For online physics lectures see also http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/679/2451

Comment: @John Rennie My question was clear: I ask for Podcasts (that is, audio files) not for video. Thanks.